# using set operators VS subqueries in sql language

Tags: sql, subquery, set-operations

Can anyone suggest me what's the difference between using set operators and subqueries in sql language? Difference parameters can be functional, performance-wise, compatibility, integration with existing systems and scalability.

Comment: The two aren't really comparable as they perform different things. You cannot express an `INTERSECT` operation in a subquery or vice-versa.

Comment: Actually we need to make a feasible report (white paper) upon the usage of set operations VS sub queries in sql language. Can yu please help me..? @Dai

Comment: If you agree to my hourly rate, sure :)

Comment: Hourly rate in the sense..?